# how to get data to textboxes from database by enter event of on another textbox with if condition in c#

Tags: c#

how to get data to textbox by enter event of on another textbox with if condition in c#

I have been trying to get data from sql database by pressing Enter key of a text box, when i enter some wrong text, it doesn't popup or message to wrong entry.

```
private void txtProdId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrng))
    {
        con.Open();
        String strSQL = "SELECT ProdName, Volume, CostPrice From tblProduct Where ProdCode=@ProdCode";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdCode", txtProdId.Text);
            using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DA.SelectCommand = cmd;
                try
                {
                    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    DA.Fill(DS);

                    foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        txtProdName.Text = row["ProdName"].ToString();
                        txtProdVol.Text = row["Volume"].ToString();
                        txtProdPrice.Text = row["CostPrice"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

could anyone help me to get result.

Comment: What is this if condition, what is the wrong text, what is right text, ect ect ect

Comment: you bind TextChanged event this method called whenever text of txtProdId changed even you delete what you typed. You need to add an if condition.

Comment: You need to add a condition which checks for enter key press. Also what do you mean by wrong text and what should it display?

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like:

```
private void txtProdId_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrng))
        {
            con.Open();
            String strSQL = "SELECT ProdName, Volume, CostPrice From tblProduct Where ProdCode=@ProdCode";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdCode", txtProdId.Text);
                using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DA.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    try
                    {
                        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                        DA.Fill(DS);

                        foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            txtProdName.Text = row["ProdName"].ToString();
                            txtProdVol.Text = row["Volume"].ToString();
                            txtProdPrice.Text = row["CostPrice"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks to all, but if the data is not found or mismatched, what will be solution. Actually I want a message box highlighting that the code doesn't exist. Could you please help me.

Comment: you should wrap your foreach loop with if statement and check data is exist. if it's solved your question please mark it as your answer. It's the first answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in Keydown events:

I guess this is the code you wanted.

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrng))
            {
                con.Open();
                String strSQL = "SELECT ProdName, Volume, CostPrice From tblProduct Where ProdCode=@ProdCode";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdCode", txtProdId.Text);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DA.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                        DA.Fill(DS);
                        try
                        {

                            if (DS.Tables.Count > 0)
                            {
                                if (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                                    {
                                        txtProdName.Text = row["ProdName"].ToString();
                                        txtProdVol.Text = row["Volume"].ToString();
                                        txtProdPrice.Text = row["CostPrice"].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    txtProdName.Text = String.Empty;
                                    txtProdVol.Text = String.Empty;
                                    txtProdPrice.Text = String.Empty;
                                    MessageBox.Show("No record found!");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("No record found!");
                            }


                        }
                        catch (Exception er)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks to all, but if the data is not found or mismatched, what will be solution. Actually I want a message box highlighting that the code doesn't exist. Could you please help me.

Comment: what do you mean `data is not found or mismatched`?

Comment: if solution helped to solved your issue then you can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

No need to TextChanged event. You can use KeyPress event for TextBox.

```
if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter){
  if(textBox1.Text = "some string"){
    //your code here...
  }
}
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, please mark as answer, so my Reputation will increase :) <3

Comment: thanks to all, but if the data is not found or mismatched, what will be solution. Actually I want a message box highlighting that the code doesn't exist. Could you please help me.

Comment: Actually, You can declare a variable that equals to Dataset's number of rows, or smth like that. for example, When i want to check if data exists or not, I use DataReader associated with command, then get all for example user's IDs or Names to List<string> then check it's count. Maybe, it is not maching with your problem, but i think it must be somethink like that. :)